# MySQL index_merge is causing the query to run 10x slower

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing, merge

I have a table with the following properties :

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | <null>  | auto_increment |
| c2                    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | <null>  |                |
| c3                    | int(11)      | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c4                    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c5                    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c6                    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | <null>  |                |
| c7                    | int(11)      | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c8                    | int(11)      | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c9                    | datetime     | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c10                   | datetime     | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c11                   | char(40)     | YES  | UNI | <null>  |                |
| c12                   | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |
| c13                   | text         | YES  |     | <null>  |                |
| c14                   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | <null>  |                |
| c15                   | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | <null>  |                |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`show index from table_one;` shows the following output :

```
+-------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name                                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name           | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table_one         |          0 | PRIMARY                                          |            1 | id                    | A         |     1621972 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          0 | c11                                              |            1 | c11                   | A         |     1621972 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          0 | c2_c6_c8_and_c14_unique                          |            1 | c2                    | A         |     1621972 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          0 | c2_c6_c8_and_c14_unique                          |            2 | c6                    | A         |     1621972 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          0 | c2_c6_c8_and_c14_unique                          |            3 | c8                    | A         |     1621972 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          0 | c2_c6_c8_and_c14_unique                          |            4 | c14                   | A         |     1621972 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          1 | c12                                              |            1 | c12                   | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          1 | c6                                               |            1 | c6                    | A         |       20794 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          1 | c14                                              |            1 | c14                   | A         |         577 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| table_one         |          1 | c15                                              |            1 | c15                   | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Now, when I run the following query, it takes around 5.8 seconds average :

```
select * from table_one
    where c6 = 12345 and c14 = 12
    limit 10 offset 0;
```

When I run `explain` on the above query, it says it has used `index_merge`:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type        | possible_keys               | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                   |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_one           | index_merge | .......................     | c14, c6 | 5,5     | NULL                          |    9 | Using intersect(c14,c6);|
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
```

But if I force the table to use index on `c6` only, it returns results in 0.6 seconds average :

```
select * from table_one force index(c6) where c6 = 12345 and c14 = 12 limit 10 offset 0;
```

Why is MySQL using `index_merge` on its own and making it slow? I am aware that I don't have composite index on `c6, c14`, but they exist individually.

Also, the `explain` query for the force index shows more count in the rows accessed to perform the query, but is still 10x faster.

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type        | possible_keys               | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows   | Extra                   |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_one           | ref         | .......................     | c6      | 5       | const                         | 22388  | Using where;            |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

This is causing our production to go down when someone hits the APIs at a high rate. MySQL just doesn't return any results for 59 seconds and the query gets timed out.

Plus, I can't really add composite indexes or change schema without downtime since we already have 2 million entries in it.

The current temporary fix is to add the `force index(c6)` to the query, but I am not really sure how scalable it would be or if we might end up having problems later on.

**EDIT 1**
Could the slowness be because of the order in which the `index_merge` is done?

More information regarding `c6` and `c14`: Consider `c6` as countries and `c14` as states.

**EDIT 2 : 2020-06-15 07:52:35 UTC :**
I tried running the query by forcing the index of `c14` and it turns out to be slower by roughly 3x:

```
select * from table_one force index(c14) where c6 = 12345 and c14 = 12 limit 10 offset 0;
```

The query took 2.1 seconds.

And the `explain` query gives the following output:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type        | possible_keys               | key     | key_len | ref                           | rows   | Extra                   |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_one           | ref         | .......................     | c14     | 5       | const                         | 730    | Using where;            |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------+--------+-------------------------+
```

The rows to be accessed by the query is 30x less than when the index is forced on `c6`. i.e. here the rows are 730, whereas with the previous query, its 22k. What factors can make this index slow even with lesser rows to access?

Some more information if it helps in any manner :

```
mysql> select count(*) from table_one where c14 is null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     7490 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from table_one;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1936278 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.68 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from table_one where c6 is null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What times do you get when using `force index(c14)`?   It will probable be very slow....    I think another solution might be to drop index c14.?

Comment: You can use tools like https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html to implement a schema change without downtime. Also if you are not using replication, you can check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-performance.html#innodb-online-ddl-locking-options

Comment: @Luuk I shall try forcing on `c14` and get back with the numbers.

@OlegKomarov I can't really modify the schema at the moment. Sorry for that :/

Comment: @Luuk I have added more information in the question. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @RohanChougule When you do not put a Date/Time in additional information in your question, we have no idea what date or time the information was added, so we do not know the age of your information listed above. And for future reference - any 'slow' query should be accompanied with the EXPLAIN ...... before we have to ask for it, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have updated the recent edit with the timestamp. And regarding the `EXPLAIN` query for slow queries, I have included all the output in the question already. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: @RohanChougule  In the group of 3 selects, there are no EXPLAIN SELECT ..... to give us any clue on what the OPTIMIZER decided to do with your query.  Changing EXPLAIN output to be ...... instead of reporting the EXPLAIN results only leads to confusion.

Comment: It looks like the combination of first looking via index on C6, and then index in C14, make things perform bad. By now you probable also found the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-intersection  Quickest improvement is given below (answer from @WilsonHauck)

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
use (dbname);
ALTER TABLE table_one ADD INDEX table_one_c6_and_c14 (c6,c14);

remove the force request in your query.

And let us know how long it took to create the multi column index, please.
And the time to complete your query, now that an appropriate index is available.

Comment: And `DROP INDEX c6` since it will be the prefix of the new index.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks for the suggestion. That is indeed the ideal way to go when I have queries using those two columns. But I can't really modify them at the moment. Else I would have gathered the data for further analysis. Sorry for that :/.

Comment: @RickJames Yep. A composite index of `(c6, c14)` will help me in case of individual index requirement on `c6`. But I can't really change the schema at the moment. Trying to understand it before taking the further step if possible.

Comment: @RohanChougule - A suitable composite index is _perhaps always_ faster than "index merge intersect".  Is there a reason you can't add the index?  What version of MySQL?  Newer versions make adding an index less invasive.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the info. I shall look into it. But before that, I have added some more data in the question regarding the individual indexes. Can you please have a look at them as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
    from  table_one force index(c14)
    where  c6 = 12345
      and  c14 = 12
    limit  10 offset 0;
```

Discussion:

1. You forced it to use `INDEX(c14)`
2. It will reach into that index at the first entry for `c14 = 12`.
3. Then it will scan, quite efficiently, across the rows with "12".
4. Each will be checked for `c6 = 12345`.  This is not as efficient as if there were `INDEX(c14, c6)`.
5. It might find 10 (cf `limit`) such rows quickly, or it might have to step over thousands of rows with the 'wrong' value of c6.

That is, the query time (for *this* query) depends a lot on the distribution of the data.

With `INDEX(c14, c6)`, only 10 index rows need be touched -- much faster, *and* (relatively) consistent speed.

`INDEX(c6, c14)` would as fast as the same as `INDEX(c14, c6)`.

More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql